# How to get a new access token using refresh token google oAuth2 using node js client library

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using googleapis library for Node js.
I want a get a new access token using the refresh token.

At the time of Authorization(first time), I requested offline access and stored the access and refresh token returned using `code`.

```
const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
    return res.status(301).redirect('http://localhost:3000');
```

And I generated auth URL using below code

```
 const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: scopes,
    response_type: 'code',
  });
```

Now,
Question1:
How can I get an access token using refresh token for a specific user, I tried below but getting the error `No refresh token set`

```
oauth2Client
    .getRequestHeaders()
    .then((res) => console.log('res', res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

There was method `refreshAccessToken` but it's deprecated now

I also tried making a POST req to the below URL to get a new access token and that worked
`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`
But is it a good way to call an external API to get this. Isn't there any built-in way in the library to get this done?

Thanks in advance, please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i use. Note how the refresh token is stored in TOKEN_PATH, and getAccessToken is used to fetch a new access token as needed.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// npm install googleapis


// Desktop app credentials from Google Cloud console.
const CREDENTIALS = 'C:\\Youtube\\dev\\credentials.json';
// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS, (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    drive.files.list({
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
        const files = res.data.files;
        if (files.length) {
            console.log('Files:');
            files.map((file) => {
                console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('No files found.');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you tell me how will it ensure that the new access token I am getting is of a specific user, and is it necessary to store tokens on files e.g. TOKEN_PATH can't I store them in DB?